# Set videoview position in constraint layout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

**main_acitivity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!--suppress ALL -->
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:id="@+id/main"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Then in java I do the next

```
vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);

ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams pararams = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) vv.getLayoutParams();
int ch=vv.getHeight();
pararams.height = vv.getWidth();

vv.setLayoutParams(pararams);
```

HOW TO MAKE ELEMENT VERTICALLY CENTERED AFTER THAT? I did vv.setY, I did margins, I tried do stuff with xml - nothing work, video either in the top or stretched through all window

Currently :

[image]

I need :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add below properties

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
```

I hope this can help you!

Comment: I tried this one. The problem is that I need width equals to window width, and height equals to width. Last four properties stretch view to all window size

Comment: You means you need to as a square as per device?

Comment: Yes, as a square

Comment: can you share image of your issue?

Comment: What is issue generated when you are use my answer code? because this make centre as you want.

Comment: I didn’t try it, but You wrote 200dp. What if my screen is less than 200dp, for example. Or I understand something wrong? I trying Your code, wait...

Comment: Also, should I keep my java code where I change height?

Comment: set height & width as 0dp or wrap_content and remove your java code.

Comment: Thank You(however 0dp firtsly wrote Wahdat Kashmiri)

Comment: Umm, actually I didn’t try, I put wrap_content instantly

Answer (score 1):

Create four Guidelines using constraint layout with percentage 25% from TOP , 25% from BOTTOM , 25% from RIGHT , 25% from BOTTOM and then create your VIdeoview 
You can adjust percentage as per the requirement then according to the screen size it will arrange accordingly.

```
<VideoView
android:id="@+id/videoView1"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guidelinetop"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guidelinebottom"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guidelineleft"
app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guidelineright"/>
```

Comment: 1) Im very new to it. How to create guideline?

Comment: No , in xml 
https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html

Comment: four Guidelines? why not use use `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.25"`
 and `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.25"` ?

Comment: @TamirAbutbul then how can you give contraints to the views?

Comment: I think that because he wants the view to be in the middle of the screen you can simply center it vertically, don't you agree?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <!--suppress ALL -->
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
   android:background="#000000">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Should I leave java code? I mean, where I change height?

Comment: Yes let VideoView render things itself as if you try to fix height runtime it might impact rendering.